# Why is the passed date from frontend not the same as in backend (Java) in ms

Tags: java, angularjs, date, spring-mvc

I'm developing an application with AngularJS in the frontend and Java (with Spring) in the backend.
I noticed that the displayed dates of a `profile`-entity in the frontend are not the same as in the database.
So I debugged the moment when I'm saving a date and found that in the frontend (right when the date is saved - `$scope.selectedProfile.$save`) the date has the following value:

```
$scope.selectedProfile.projects[1].start -> Date: 2017-10-31T23:00:00.000Z
$scope.selectedProfile.projects[1].start.getTime() -> 1509490800000
```

Next I arrive at the breakpoint in the backend at the return line:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/profiles", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ProfileController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public Profile update(@RequestBody Profile profile) {
      return this.repository.save(profile);
  }

}
```

And the date has following value:

```
profile.projects.get(1).start -> (Date) “Tue Oct 31 23:00:00 CET 2017”
profile.projects.get(1).start.getTime() -> 1509487200000
```

Isn't the problem occuring here already? - because shouldn't the "getTime()" functions return the same number in both frontend and backend since they aren't dependend on timezones?

The problem is when I export the values into a Word file and display the month it writes "October" even though the date that is shown in the frontend is November 1st.

Does anyone have some ideas what I could do?

Here's the JSON that gets passed:

```
{
  "id": 64,
  "projects": [
    {
      "id": 135,
      "project": 339,
      "start": null,
      "end": null
    },
    {
      "id": 132,
      "project": 403,
      "start": "2017-10-31T23:00:00.000Z",
      "end": null
    }
  ]
}
```

The data gets passed through this code:

```
$http.post('/profiles/profiles', profile)
```

The mapping is done automatically by Spring I think.

Comment: try to format the date

Comment: Where is the code that sends the date from the fontend to the backend? What does the JSON you send contain?

Comment: @JBNizet thx for the hint, I added that info

Comment: So the problem is on the backend. How do you parse the JSON? It seems you're still using the obsolete, awful java.util.Date class. Don't. Use java.time.Instant.

Comment: @JBNizet thx for the hint - I will try to go after that and update this post once I made any more progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are mis-understanding how dates (in both JavaScript and Java) 
depend on timezones, and I think that something is probably amiss with the way the inbound date is being parsed on the Java side.

On the client (JavaScript side), your (formatted) date is '2017-10-31T23:00:00.000Z'
and on the back-end (Java side), your (formatted) date is 'Tue Oct 31 23:00:00 CET 2017'.

Note that these two dates represent moments in time that are an hour (or 2, depending on DST) apart. The date and time portions are equivalent, but the JavaScript date is in UTC, while the Java date shows the CET timezone. As CET is UTC+1 or UTC+2 depending on DST, they are not the same.

Looks like something on the Java side is taking the UTC-formatted date string, ignoring the timezone, and deserializing it as-is into Java Date with the local (CET) timezone.

Looking at the date on the back-end after it has been inserted into the database and then retrieved again leaves open a lot of possibilities for where the bug is. You'll have to inspect it in the Spring Controller, right after it's deserialized, and then at every step along the way to the database and back out again, to see where the faulty conversion is.

Comment: I found a workaround solution: when I add this annotation above a date-type property in my java model the serialization is correct: `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone="UTC")` But I don't want to add this annotation to every variable. There must be a way to set this globally(?)

Comment: @Cold_Class if you use Jackon, you can define a default date formatter on ObjectMapper. From v2.9 of Jackson you have StdDateFormat wihich handles ISO dates. try `objectMapper.setDateFormat(new StdDateFormat().withColonInTimeZone(true));`

Comment: @StanislasKlukowski thx, I think I got it - I found an existing mapper in the coding and just added `mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));` - it seems to work now, once I've tested everything I'll write how I did it in an answer.